# Elasticsearch - Query to Determine All Unique IDs that are distance X away from a particular ID?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in this format generated from a random walk (to simulate people walking around). It is set up in this manner { location : { lat: someLat, lon: someLong }, id: uniqueId, date:date }. I am trying to write a query given a users unique ID, find how many other unique IDs came within X distance of the given ID between a certain time range. Any hints on how to accomplish this?

My idea is to have a top level filter aggregration, with a nested geo-query of some sort. I think the geo-distance query is the way to go, but I am not sure how to include it into the below query to get all of unique IDs that come within X distance of the ID I am filtering on. The query below is where I am starting from, I am filtering all documents from now - 1 day to now, where the documents user Id is the provided value. How would I check all other documents for their distances against documents that match this query?

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "date",
                "format": "MM-yyyy",
                "ranges": [
                    { "to": "now" }, 
                    { "from": "now-1d" } 
                ]
            }
        },
        "locations" : {
            "filter" : { 
              "term": { "id.keyword": "7a50ab18-886b-42a2-80ad-3d45112e3cfd" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is correct. All of this can be done using `range` & `geo_distance` filtering and `_geo_distance` sorting. You wanna filter on the query-level, not in the aggs though:

```
GET walking/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "now-1d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "20m",
            "location": {
              "lat": 48.20150179951008,
              "lon": 16.39111876487732
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
     "rings_around_loc": {
          "geo_distance": {
            "field": "location",
            "origin": {
              "lat": 48.20150179951008,
              "lon": 16.39111876487732
            },
            "unit": "m",
            "keyed": true,
            "ranges": [
              {
                "to": 10
              },
              {
                "from": 10,
                "to": 50
              },
              {
                "from": 50
              }
            ]
          }
    },
    "locations": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "id.keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 48.20150179951008,
          "lon": 16.39111876487732
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "m",
        "mode": "min",
        "distance_type": "arc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure what you need the range buckets for so I left them out.

---

Full steps to replicate:

```
PUT walking
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then `POST _bulk` this [random walk data](https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/2a351d94230b194e99b37d1b2dcac9a4)

Comment: Awesome solution. However it seems that a specific location needs to be provided to do the query. Would there be anyway to instead of considering one specific location, just use the locations from all of the documents that are returned from the query? So essentially check for other users location against the total location history for one user

Comment: I don't think that possible -- though I could be mistaken! The way you phrased your question means that you'd be interested in a user-per-user basis anyways so I'd recommend running the above script multiple times / for each point of the walk. It's a bit cumbersome but again, I don't know a more elegant way. FYI I update my answer with a `geo_distance` agg which might be of interest to you too.